# Unable to open the file in txt in python

Tags: python, ios, file, path, txt

I have difficulty importing this file so that I can use it any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
import os 
path = os.path.abspath(r'C:Users/kariwhite/Desktop/430 Python/week 4/cars.txt')
cars=open(path)
print (cars)

for line in cars:
    values = line.split ()
    print(values[0], 'has an MPG of', values[2], 'with', values[5])
    
    # TODO: Split the line into a list of strings
     
    
    # TODO: Print the sentence
     

# Close the file
cars.close()
```

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import os 
      2 path = os.path.abspath(r'C:Users/kariwhite/Desktop/430 Python/week 4/cars.txt')
----> 3 cars=open(path)
      4 print (cars)
      6 for line in cars:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kariwhite/Desktop/430 Python/week 4/C:Users/kariwhite/Desktop/430 Python/week 4/cars.txt'
```

Comment: `c:` vs. `c:/` ?

Comment: that just means that the file doesn't exist, are you sure that you types the path correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When reading files on python I'd highly recommend using the `os.path` module. It helps combine paths depending on which OS you're using. Assuming you're sure that the file exists, try the following:

```py
import os

pwd = os.path.join("c:/", "Users", "kariwhite","Desktop","430 Python", "week 4", "cars.txt")

with open(pwd, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        values = line.split() 
        #...
```

I'd highly recommend reading files using the syntax highlighted here too. `with open() as file: ...` is the best practice for file handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re working in User/kariwhite/

Try

```
os.path.abspath(“Desktop/430 Python/week 4/cars.txt”)
```

You typically have to start the path from your current working directory if it’s moving forward from there and not in a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the os.path.abspath() takes a path or file name as a parameter representing a file system path and returns a normalized version of the pathname path.

If the file actually exists in the specified directory (Users/kariwhite/Desktop/430 Python/week 4/cars.txt) and your working directory is Users/kariwhite/Desktop/430 Python/week 4 the below should work:

```
import os 
path = os.path.abspath("cars.txt")
cars=open(path)
print (cars)
```

Also, if the file is in the current working directory you could use the relative path by opening the file directly:

```
import os
cars=open("cars.txt")
print (cars)
```